# Handling possible errors in C in a simple function

Tags: c, error-handling

I have the following code:

```
// global variables
count = 0;
char arr[50][5];

main(){
   // do something
}

init(){
   count = 0;
   memset (arr, 0, sizeof(arr));
}
```

I need to return 1 if init() is successful, but 0 if not. However, I can't see how init() can technically fail. How should I implement this error handler in init()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 issues:

- You don't need to return anything if you don't want to, just make the function `void`
- Your init function is not needed as `arr` is already 0-initialized since it has static storage (global variable).

#### EDIT

> basically main() can modify count and arr, and at some point i need to
>   re-initialize the global variables using init().

If the function can be called later on it would be useful to call it "reset", "reinit", "clear" etc. "init" makes the reader think it is only called once, at the beginning

> According to the write-up i have to return 1 or 0 in init() depending
>   on whether there's an error...

In that case just say:

```
/* XXX No other return code is possible. */
return 0;
```

Comment: oh i forgot to mention that this is a homework question. basically main() can modify count and arr, and at some point i need to re-initialize the global variables using init(). according to the write-up i have to return 1 or 0 in init() depending on whether there's an error...

Comment: so memset always works all the time? should I iterate through and check the way self. suggested? is segmentation fault possible in this case?

Comment: @Mariska If `memset` fails then it does so catastrophically (for example by crashing the process), typically because it's not called right. I see no value in rechecking the array to see if `memset` did its job.